# How to pass a textbox value from view to a controller in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here i am fetching the value from database and showing it in a input field

```
<input type="text" id="ss" value="@item.Quantity"/>
```

and the value fetching from database is `1`.Then i am changing the input field value to `2`
and passing that value to the controller in a action click

```
 <a id="imgUpdate"  href="@Url.Action("Update", "Shopping", new { id = Request.QueryString["UserID"], productid = item.ProductID, qty = item.Quantity, unitrate = item.Rate })">
```

But in the controller part i am getting that `old value`1 for `qty`.But i need that `updated value 2` in `qty`

```
public ActionResult Update(string id, string productid, int qty, decimal unitrate)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int _records = UpdatePrice(id,productid,qty,unitrate);
                if (_records > 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index1", "Shopping");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("","Can Not Update");
                }
            }
            return View("Index1");
        }
```

Any suggestion?

**EDIT:**

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Update", "Shopping", FormMethod.Post))
     {

                @Html.Hidden("id", @Request.QueryString["UserID"] as string)
                @Html.Hidden("productid", item.ProductID as string)
                @Html.TextBox("qty", item.Quantity)
                @Html.Hidden("unitrate", item.Rate)

                <input type="submit" value="Update" />
     }
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use simple form:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Update", "Shopping"))
{
    <input type="text" id="ss" name="qty" value="@item.Quantity"/>
    ...
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

And add here attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(string id, string productid, int qty, decimal unitrate)
```

Comment: tried like this..while clicking input type update it is not moving into the update action..Kept a breakpoint and checked it..what is the problem here??

Comment: @bala3569 Check form action in browser (page source code), then check your inputs (binding works by input name if it exist, then by id). Your page must be reloaded after `Update` click.

Comment: ya the page gets reloaded but the value remains the same and it is not calling the update action method

Answer (score 3):

your link is generated when the page **loads** therefore it will always have the original value in it. You will need to set the link via javascript

You could also just wrap that in a form and have hidden fields for `id`, `productid`, and  `unitrate`

Here's a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/ytb2h/1/) for ya.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="ss" value="1"/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" id="go" onClick="changeUrl()"/>
<br/>
<a id="imgUpdate"  href="/someurl?quantity=1">click me</a>
```

**JS**

```
function changeUrl(){
   var url = document.getElementById("imgUpdate").getAttribute('href');
   var inputValue = document.getElementById('ss').value;
   var currentQ = GiveMeTheQueryStringParameterValue("quantity",url);
    url = url.replace("quantity=" + currentQ, "quantity=" + inputValue);
document.getElementById("imgUpdate").setAttribute('href',url)
}

    function GiveMeTheQueryStringParameterValue(parameterName, input) {
    parameterName = parameterName.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + parameterName + "=([^&#]*)");
    var results = regex.exec(input);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

this could be cleaned up and expanded as you need it but the example works

Comment: am not using jquery..is there any other way without jquery??like asp.net webforms

Answer (score 3):

When you want to pass new information to your application, you need to use POST form. In Razor you can use the following

**View Code:**

```
@* By default BeginForm use FormMethod.Post *@
@using(Html.BeginForm("Update")){
     @Html.Hidden("id", Model.Id)
     @Html.Hidden("productid", Model.ProductId)
     @Html.TextBox("qty", Model.Quantity)
     @Html.TextBox("unitrate", Model.UnitRate)
     <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

**Controller's actions**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Update(){
     //[...] retrive your record object
     return View(objRecord);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(string id, string productid, int qty, decimal unitrate)
{
      if (ModelState.IsValid){
           int _records = UpdatePrice(id,productid,qty,unitrate);
           if (_records > 0){                    {
              return RedirectToAction("Index1", "Shopping");
           }else{                   
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Can Not Update");
           }
      }
      return View("Index1");
 }
```

Note that alternatively, if you want to use `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity)` you can either have an input with the name (respectecting case) `"Quantity"` or you can change your POST Update() to receive an object parameter, that would be the same type as your strictly typed view. Here's an example:

**Model**

```
public class Record {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitRate { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Update")){
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
     @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductId)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model=> model.Quantity)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UnitRate)
     <input type="submit" value="Update" />
}
```

**Post Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Record rec){ //Alternatively you can also use FormCollection object as well 
   if(TryValidateModel(rec)){
        //update code
   }
   return View("Index1");
}
```

Comment: tried like this..while clicking input type update it is not moving into the update action..Kept a breakpoint and checked it..what is the problem here??

Comment: @bala3569 typically you have two actions, one POST and one get, GET will return (get) the view and POST will save your data. I'll update my answer

Comment: Ya it is working fine..But the problem is i cannot able to pass the query string in that update post method

Comment: on first load page url is like this http://localhost:61110/Shopping/Index1?UserID=Admin1 but after update click it is like http://localhost:61110/Shopping/Index1...How to pass query string here...look at my edit

Comment: @bala3569 Make sure you form fields are matching your Action signature.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just try to answer the question but my examples very simple because I'm new at mvc. Hope this help somebody.

```
    [HttpPost]  ///This function is in my controller class
    public ActionResult Delete(string txtDelete)
    {
        int _id = Convert.ToInt32(txtDelete); // put your code           
    }
```

This code is in my controller's cshtml

```
  >   @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "LibraryManagement"))
 {
<button>Delete</button>
@Html.Label("Enter an ID number");
@Html.TextBox("txtDelete")  }
```

Just make sure the textbox name and your controller's function input are the same name and type(string).This way, your function get the textbox input.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your view to check the output from each. The first one updates when the view is called a second time.  My controller uses the key ShowCreateButton and has the optional parameter _createAction with a default value - you can change this to your key/parameter

```
@Html.TextBox("_createAction", null, new { Value = (string)ViewBag.ShowCreateButton })
@Html.TextBox("_createAction", ViewBag.ShowCreateButton )
@ViewBag.ShowCreateButton
```