# Url.Action not passing parameter to index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller I have the following code:

```
    public ActionResult Index(int? videoId, int languageId = 0)
        {

               //Some code 
        }
```

Then in my .chtml page I reference it like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "VideoLanguage", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.Hidden("videoId", Model.VideoId)
     @Html.Hidden("videoLanguageId", Model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId)

    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId, ViewData["LanguageId"] as SelectList)
    </div>
    <div>
          <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "VideoLanguage",new { videoId = Model.VideoId, languageId = Model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId })" class="linkbutton">Add Language</a>
    </div>

... code keeps going
```

So what happens when i click the button, the selected value for LanguageId from the drop down isnt passed. The original value is.

Comment: You're not doing it right. Can you post the code for your Model here? If you do that, I'll tell you how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "VideoLanguage",new { videoId = Model.VideoId, languageId = Model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId })" class="linkbutton">Add Language</a>
```

Is set when the page loads, so the values in the HTML will be hardcoded in.  What you need to do is either set the hyperlink parameters in Javascript OR use:

```
<input type="submit" value="Index" />
```

See [How to pass a textbox value from view to a controller in MVC 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12954806/how-to-pass-a-textbox-value-from-view-to-a-controller-in-mvc-4?rq=1)

Comment: This answer helped me understand what the problem was. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "VideoLanguage", FormMethod.Post, new { videoId = Model.VideoId, languageId = Model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId }))
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your params to the @Html.BeginForm helper and just submit the form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "VideoLanguage", FormMethod.Post, new { videoId = Model.VideoId, languageId = Model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId }))
{
     @Html.Hidden("videoId", Model.VideoId)
     @Html.Hidden("videoLanguageId", Model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId)

    <div>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedLanguage.LanguageId, ViewData["LanguageId"] as SelectList)
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type="submit" value="Add Language"/>
    </div>

... code keeps going
}
```

in your Controller you also should have two methods GET and SET with the same name:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
//Here just get a view
        }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int? videoId, int languageId = 0)
        {
 //Here code to save in database
        }
```